# What does UNDEF and notype() mean when seeing the C++ library information using dumpbin?

Tags: c++, dumpbin

I used dumpbin /symbols to see the library I created. Some functions have **UNDEF**  **notype** in the output. What does that mean? Is there any *link* to study the structure of dumpbin output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can take a look at [the MSDN documentation for `dumpbin /SYMBOLS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b842y285.aspx):

> This option displays the COFF symbol table. Symbol tables exist in all
>   object files. A COFF symbol table appears in an image file only if it
>   is linked with /DEBUG.
>
> The following is a description of the output for /SYMBOLS. Additional
>   information on the meaning of /SYMBOLS output can be found by looking
>   in winnt.h (IMAGE_SYMBOL and IMAGE_AUX_SYMBOL), or COFF documentation.
>
> Given the following sample dump:

```
Dump of file main.obj
File Type: COFF OBJECT

COFF    SYMBOL    TABLE
000    00000000   DEBUG      notype      Filename      | .file
      main.cpp
002   000B1FDB   ABS      notype      Static      | @comp.id
003   00000000   SECT1      notype      Static      | .drectve
      Section length       26, #relocs   0, #linenums    0, checksum 722C964F
005   00000000   SECT2      notype      Static      | .text
      Section length      23, #relocs      1, #linenums    0, checksum 459FF65F, selection    1 (pick no duplicates)
007   00000000   SECT2      notype ()   External      | _main
008   00000000   UNDEF      notype ()   External      | ?MyDump@@YAXXZ (void __cdecl MyDump(void))

String Table Size = 0x10 bytes

Summary

      26 .drectve
      23 .text
```

> The following description, for lines that begin with a symbol number,
>   describes columns that have information relevant to users:
>
> The first three-digit number is the symbol index/number.
>
> - If the third column contains SECTx, the symbol is defined in that
>     section of the object file. But **if UNDEF appears, it is not defined in
>     that object and must be resolved elsewhere.**
> - The fifth column (Static, External) tells whether the symbol is
>     visible only within that object, or whether it is public (visible
>     externally). A Static symbol, _sym, wouldn't be linked to a Public
>     symbol _sym; these would be two different instances of functions named
>     _sym.
> - The last column in a numbered line is the symbol name, both
>     decorated and undecorated.

And `notype()` means exactly what it says on the tin: it has no type.

Comment: There is a huge difference between `notype` and `notype ()`. The first designates a data-label, the second a function-label. Microsoft's LINKER doesn't care about that difference by default, but LIB does and will not resolve one type with the other. Have a look at the win32 extensions to COFF for which bits in the type field actually do have a meaning, despite all being summed up as `notype`.

Comment: "notype() means exactly what it says on the tin: it has no type" What does "type" mean in this context?